# Fill Cytoscape.js Panzoom with Server Data Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, cytoscape.js

I use `Cytoscape.js Panzoom`. It works fine for static Data. Now I need to fill the Graph with Data coming for the Server.

Here is my Configuration File

// Code goes here

```
var CanvasApp = function () {
            var cy;
            var playground;

            return {
                init: function () {
                    var elem = document.createElement("div");
                    elem.id = 'cy';

                    playground = document.getElementById('playground');
                    playground.appendChild(elem);

                    cy = $(elem).cytoscape({
                        style: [
                            {
                                selector: 'node',
                                css: {
                                    'content': 'data(name)'
                                }
                            },

                            {
                                selector: 'edge',
                                css: {
                                    'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
                                }
                            }
                        ],

                        elements: {
                            nodes: [
                                {data: {id: 'j', name: 'Jerry'}},
                                {data: {id: 'e', name: 'Elaine'}},
                                {data: {id: 'k', name: 'Kramer'}},
                                {data: {id: 'g', name: 'George'}}
                            ],
                            edges: [
                                {data: {source: 'j', target: 'e'}},
                                {data: {source: 'j', target: 'k'}},
                                {data: {source: 'j', target: 'g'}},
                                {data: {source: 'e', target: 'j'}},
                                {data: {source: 'e', target: 'k'}},
                                {data: {source: 'k', target: 'j'}},
                                {data: {source: 'k', target: 'e'}},
                                {data: {source: 'k', target: 'g'}},
                                {data: {source: 'g', target: 'j'}}
                            ]
                        }
                    }).cytoscape('get');

                    $(elem).cytoscapePanzoom();

                },

                destroy: function () {
                    cy.destroy();
                    cy = null;
                }
            }
        };


        var app = new CanvasApp();
```

How can I configure  or make it to work with my Data in the Server using Ajax?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

One option is to specify the elements as a promise to load them at init:

```
let cy = new Cytoscape({
  elements: fetch('blah/blah/blah.json').then( res => res.json() )
});
```

See the docs: http://js.cytoscape.org/#init-opts/elements

Or just make an HTTP request whichever way you prefer and use the response (e.g. load Cytoscape) afterwards, as you would generally.

See also [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), [`XMLHTTPRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)